# Flutter Bad state: SVG did not specify dimensions

Tags: android, html, flutter, dart, svg

I am developing a newspaper app where the API provides the body of a news post in `HTML` content, the same `HTML` they use to show news on their website.

But the problem is many of the images of news bodies that are being shown on the website do not show up in the app.

For rendering the `HTML` content I am using the `flutter_widget_from_html` package.

The below code is what I am using,

```
Container(
              child: HtmlWidget(
              NewsPost.news_content,
              webView: true,
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: FontSizeController.newsDetailsContent,
                  fontFamily: 'metaSerifPro'
              ),
            )
          ),
```

***For instance, for the below news the website shows this image,***

[image]

...

***But when I open the news in the app the above image does not show up,***

[image]

...

***You can see the app just shows the caption of the image but not the image itself.***

When I open a news post, at the first time it throws the below error, but after hot reload that error goes away although still the image does not show up.

```
Bad state: SVG did not specify dimensions
 
The SVG library looks for a `viewBox` or `width` and `height` attribute to determine the viewport boundary of the SVG.  Note that these attributes, as with all SVG attributes, are case sensitive. During processing, the following attributes were found:
 []
```

I found out the package `flutter_widget_from_html` depends on another package `flutter_svg` which requires these certain attributes mentioned in the error.

Then I tried the following packages,

1. `flutter_html`
2. `webview_flutter`
3. `webview_flutter_plus`

In the case of the above three packages it throws no error but still the image in the body does not show rather there remains a white gap.

The other relevant questions that I found did not solve my problem.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky my bad, edited.

Comment: Did you try adding a width and height to the widget?

Comment: @Andrej ... yeah, I tried adding height and width to the parent Container to the HtmlWidget. Did not work.